# Распознавание лиц Emgu c#

Tags: c#, wpf, распознавание-образов, emgu

Программа обнаружает лица и распознает имена через текстовый файл. Но если появляется лицо, имени которого нет в файле, то он берет имя первого и ставит. Как сделать чтобы он писал что такой человек не найден. Код приведен ниже

```
foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
        {
            t = t + 1;
            result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);


            if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
            {

                MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

                EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(trainingImages.ToArray(), labels.ToArray(), 3000, ref termCrit);


                name = recognizer.Recognize(result);

                currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new System.Drawing.Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

            }


            NamePersons[t - 1] = name;
            NamePersons.Add("");

            label1.Content = facesDetected[0].Length.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: `name = recognizer.Recognize(result);` - эта строка? Тогда показывайте этот метод, и что собой представляет переменная `result`, здесь же нет телепатов!?

Comment: изменил код. Смотрите